# Static keyword in function parameter

Tags: c, static, function, parameter-passing

I've just found this function definition in some embedded code:

```
float round_float_to_4(static float inputval);
```

I'm familiar with other uses for **static** (global variables, functions and local variables), but this is the first time I see it as specifier for function parameter. I assume that this forces compiler to use fixed memory location for **inputval** instead of stack?

Comment: In gcc I get `error: storage class specified for parameter x`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is non standard.  I'd guess the same thing as you, and I'm not surprised of such extension in compilers having an embedded target.

Comment: You are right. I checked the compiler's (Microchip C18) manual and found this: "Function parameters can have storage class auto or static. An auto parameter is placed on the software stack, enabling reentrancy. A static parameter is allocated globally, enabling direct access for generally smaller code."

Answer (score 9):

That's not valid. The only valid place where `static` may be used in a function parameter i'm aware of is in an array dimension

```
float round_float_to_4(float inputval[static 4]);
```

Saying that `inputval` will, in all calls to this function, point to memory providing at least `4` floats (this is a C99 addition, it doesn't appear in C89).

Comment: @KennyTM, yes it means that the parameter declaration is equivalent to `int * const y`: So it changes the toplevel qualification. The `4` in absence of `static`, however, has no real meaning this time.

Answer (score 2):

As per C standard,

> The only storage-class specifier that shall occur in a parameter
>   declaration is register.

Answer (score 1):

Many embedded devices have a seriously limited stack, such a feature would be of great benefit in reducing the chances of stack overflow, while still giving you the opportunity for re entrant code.

Smaller chips don't have any opportunity to put variables on the stack, so all parameters are implicitly memory locations.